# Cómo detectar el fin de fichero en C

Tags: c, unix

Tengo que leer un fichero línea a línea utilizando llamadas al sistema en C pero no sé cómo detectar el final del fichero y estoy obteniendo todo el rato Segmentation Fault porque en la última línea no hay `\n` y se queda infinitamente leyendo el último carácter.

Esta es mi función leer linea: *(fd es el descriptor de fichero)*

```
int leerLinea(int fd, char linea[]){
    char c;
    int leidos=0;
    int i=0;
    read(fd,&c,1);
    while(c!='\n' && c!=NULL){
        linea[i]=c;
        i++;
        leidos++;
        read(fd,&c,1);
    }
    linea[i] = '\n'; //por si quieres tener el \n en lo leido
    return leidos;
}
```

Comment: Lo que hace es leer una línea pero cuando llega a la última línea de un fichero se queda infinitamente porque no hay un ```\n``` al final de esa línea, supongo que te habrá funcionado porque habrás añadido una línea en blanco al final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en que sumaba 1 a `leídos` cada vez que entraba en el bucle en lugar de sumarlo después de comprobar si la llamada al sistema había funcionado bien y mi programa principal tenía la condición de que si `leídos > 0` invocaba otra vez a `leerLinea()` por lo que se creaba un bucle infinito ya que leídos siempre era > 0, con su respectivo Segmentation Fault. Tampoco hacía falta comprobar que el carácter no fuese NULL.

```
int leerLinea(int fd, char linea[]){
    char c;
    int leidos=0;
    int fin=1;
    int i=0;
    read(fd,&c,1);
    while(c!='\n' && fin !=0){
        linea[i]=c;
        i++;
        if(fin = read(fd,&c,1)>0) leidos++;
    }
    linea[i] = '\n'; //por si quieres tener el \n en lo leido
    return leidos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo en la condicional si llegó al final del fichero:

```
int leerLinea(int fd, char linea[]){
char c;
int leidos=0;
int fin = 1;
int i=0;
read(fd,&c,1);
while(c != '\n' && c!=NULL && fin != 0){
    linea[i]=c;
    i++;
    leidos++;
    fin = read(fd,&c,1);
}
linea[i] = '\n'; //por si quieres tener el \n en lo leido
return leidos;
```

}

Comment: No me funciona tampoco con el EOF

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de la función read.

Comment: Read es una llamada al sistema de UNIX

Comment: Pues ya está, si devuelve cero es que llegó al final del archivo.

Comment: Esto es incorrecto. `EOF` **no** es un valor que se puede representar en un `char`, por lo tanto `c != EOF` siempre es cierto. `c!=NULL` tampoco tiene sentido. `NULL` es un puntero, y `c` no.

Comment: Lo voy a quitar para que no quede el error yo entendía (c = getchar())  !=EOF); pero él usa read que devuelve cero si llegó al final.